# Group and count duplicate values in arraylist java

Tags: java, arraylist

I have used ArrayLists in my application, so I do not want to move to HashMaps as I have seen a few answers using this but did not work in my case.

I am creating my final high school project which is a study time table scheduler. I have managed to sort the ArrayList by date of the exam, but now I am trying to analyze the time table to rate it and compare the ratings with other generated timetables to give the user the best timetable (with the highest value).

I have gotten the timetable to output what they will be doing on each day ie: Afrikaans, IT, LO, Maths, Afrikaans, Afrikaans, etc.

But it seems that it duplicates on the last one for a long time even if the two last exams are within 2 days or very close together, the last one will be more dominant in the entire list. Like this:

```
Exam Dates:
LO = 2 Sep
Maths = 5 Sep
IT = 9 Sep
Afrikaans = 10 Sep

Results:
LO
IT
Afrikaans
Maths
IT
Afrikaans
Afrikaans
Afrikaans
Afrikaans
```

As you can see, the result is much more weighted towards the last given subject.

Now I am trying to compare and group the data so I can see how many days were allocated to each subject, so using the above example I need it to look like this:

```
LO = 1
Maths = 1
IT = 2
Afrikaans = 5
```

So far I have this:

```
ArrayList<Day> days = new ArrayList<Day>();
For(int i = 0; i < timeTable.size(); i++) {
    // need to group the days here
    if(days.contains(timeTable.get(i))) {
        days.get(i).incrementNumberOfDays();
    } else {
        days.add(timeTable.get(i));
    }
}
```

But that is not grouping the data and counting the duplicates.
Please help, my project is due in a week and I have spent two months on it. I am almost finished and am stuck here.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried counting sort? It will give you the number of duplicates along the way and you will end up with the values grouped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `java.util.Collections.frequency`:

```
int count = Collections.frequency(timeTable, value);
```

Edit: answer to your last question in comment:

> Surely there is a quick simple way to say this value occurred 3 times
>   in the arraylist?

Comment: This is giving the same result, always returns -1, even after printing `days` out I can see that it is not grouping the data

Comment: There are 7 classes manipulating the data to get to this point. And the data originally comes from a database. Surely there is a quick simple way to say `this value occurred 3 times in the arraylist`?

Answer (score 0):

It's necessary to mention that in your `timeTable`, assuming it contains two *same* `Day` - `Afrikaans  - 1`, when you see they are the same, the `contains` function doesn't think so. Although they have the same value for each property, but not the hashcode.

You need to override the function of `equals()` to make sure that when comparing two `Day`, if they have the same value, they are regarded as one object.

Sorry for my poor English, hope you can get it.